# Can't open rpt file in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

How to open Crystal report file using visual studio 2013?

I tried but it shown some binary data.

Comment: what data format do you expect to see?

Comment: Do you even have CR installed?? Thats your problem.

Comment: i installed crystal report in my machine, if i try to open .rpt file, it shown "invalid access key" and "The operation could not completed.Class not registered" error